# firebase_auth.dart:18:67: Error: Member not found, How to solve this flutter firebase error?

Tags: firebase, flutter

auth version: firebase_auth-0.16.1

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth 
0.16.1/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:18:67: Error: Member not found: 'instance'.
  static final FirebaseAuth instance = FirebaseAuth._(FirebaseApp.instance);
```

environment:

```
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

pub dependencies :

#firebase dependencies

```
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7
firebase_core: ^1.0.4
firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
firebase_database: ^3.0.7
firebase_messaging: ^9.1.1
firebase_storage: ^8.0.4
```

dependency_overrides:

```
  permission_handler_platform_interface: ^2.0.2 
  firebase_core: ^1.0.4
  plugin_platform_interface: ^1.0.2
  firebase_storage_web: ^1.0.4
  http: ^0.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on a quite old version of the Firebase Authentication package:

```
firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
```

The [latest version](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) is 3.3.7, so I recommend updating to a newer version to see if that fixes the problem.